# Format Git stdout to Evernote list items

Tags: git, evernote

I am using the following command:

```
git log --all --pretty="format:%s%w(0,8,8)%+b" | sed '/^$/d'
```

Which gives me the following output from `git log`.

```
Commit subject line
    Commit description line. This line can span
    multiple lines.
    Also new lines as well
```

When I paste this into my Evernote as list items it looks like the following.

- Commit subject line
- Commit description line. This can span multiple lines.
- Also new lines as well.

I want to paste into Evernote but have the output look like the following.

- Commit subject line

  - Commit description line. This can span multiple lines.
  - Also new lines as well.

Falling short on finding a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I figured on Mac. It is not clean but you'll see what I've done.

```
hex=`( echo "<ul>" && git log --all --pretty="format:<li>%s%w(0,8,8)<ul><li>%+b</li></ul></li>" | sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's|<ul><li></li></ul>||' && echo "</ul>" ) | hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2x"'`
osascript -e "set the clipboard to «data HTML${hex}»"
```

After running the command above, you can paste it into Evernote.

Comment: Words can't express how happy I am to have this finally working. Thank you so much!